# console.log and JSON.parse returning error

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, syntax, console.log

I am attempting to parse a JSON string and log it to the Chrome console. The string validates using JSONLint. Why then is Chrome is returning the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %"?

```
<script>console.log(JSON.parse('{"header-top":{"name":"Header Top","id":"header-top","description":"","class":"","before_widget":"\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E","after_widget":"\u003C\/li\u003E\n","before_title":"\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E","after_title":"\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"}}'));</script>
```

Here is the JSON, Pretty Printed:

```
{
    "header-top": {
        "name": "Header Top",
        "id": "header-top",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "header": {
        "name": "Header",
        "id": "header",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "header-bottom": {
        "name": "Header Bottom",
        "id": "header-bottom",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "content-top": {
        "name": "Content Top",
        "id": "content-top",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "content": {
        "name": "Content",
        "id": "content",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "content-bottom": {
        "name": "Content Bottom",
        "id": "content-bottom",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "footer-top": {
        "name": "Footer Top",
        "id": "footer-top",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "footer": {
        "name": "Footer",
        "id": "footer",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    },
    "footer-bottom": {
        "name": "Footer Bottom",
        "id": "footer-bottom",
        "description": "",
        "class": "",
        "before_widget": "\u003Cli id=\u0022%1$s\u0022 class=\u0022widget %2$s\u0022\u003E",
        "after_widget": "\u003C\/li\u003E\n",
        "before_title": "\u003Ch2 class=\u0022widgettitle\u0022\u003E",
        "after_title": "\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: try formatting the JSON to see if that gives you any hints.

Comment: @DanielA.White I shortened the example and posted my actual JSON, Pretty Printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because of the `\u0022` character in one of your strings.

The problem with it is that when the string literal (the long JSON) is evaluated it's being replaced with `"` (a quote character), which leads to some JSON string becoming broken:

```
"\u0022"
```

becomes

```
"""
```

So technically the given JSON is a valid JSON, but it cannot be used as-is in an environment that evaluates `\uXXXX` sequences.

So you could, for example, read it from some other source - eg as a response from AJAX request, but you cannot use it as a string literal in JS code.

Comment: so it needs to be `\\u0022`.

Comment: @DanielA.White depends on what "needs" means :-) Because then it will be broken in some different way.

Comment: Thanks @DanielA. White. I replaced all "\" with "\\" in my html and it works now.

Comment: @skibulk yep, I realized that it would require much more replacements

Comment: Also, `"\u003C\/h2\u003E\n"` is a string literal containing a newline.

Comment: @skibulk, Note that replacing all `\` with `\\` is unsafe.  For example, if your JS were `console.log(JSON.parse('"\', alert(32)))//"'))` and you replaced all `\` with `\\` you would end up with `console.log(JSON.parse('"\\', alert(32)))//"'))` which would alert 32.  When you escape backslashes in the body of a  single-quoted string, you also need to escape single quotes.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Is there something wrong with using a newline in JSON? Thanks for the security warning. I already sanitize `&'"<>` characters.

Comment: @skibulk http://json.org/ new line is a valid character in JSON (not in JS string literals though).

Comment: But `\n` isn't actually a new line? It's a proxy for the new line character, which is converted to a new line character upon parsing the JSON? The browser doesn't evaluate it like the other `\uXXXX` sequences, does it? That's all handled by the javascript, I think.

Comment: @skibulk it depends where it's used: in JSON a real `0xA` character can be used between any tokens; in string values it's only exact `\n` (2 characters, slash followed by `n`) that is allowed.